# What is the difference between the known_hosts file in the .ssh folder in my home directory and the one in /etc/ssh?

Tags: ssh

I have no deep understanding of SSH and I am a bit baffled about the relation between the `/home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts` (or `~/.ssh/known_hosts`) and `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` files.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: I want to automate ssh set up for our development env. I put the same public key to authorized_keys and ~/.ssh/known_hosts. But I am getting warnning - man-in-the-middle attack. I am trying ssh localhost. Complain about different fingerprint

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `known_hosts` file in your home directory is where ssh automatically stores the identity of every new server *you* visit. Other users will have their own `known_hosts` file, of course.

The file in `/etc` is the same thing, except that it can only be written to manually, and is shared between all users of the system.

A typical use for the `/etc` file is for the system administrator to enter the identities of all the servers inside your organization. This way each user will not have to answer "yes" when they first visit local resources, but, more importantly, it improves security.

The purpose of the `known_hosts` file is to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks by ensuring that you are connecting to the same server that you connected to last time (it hasn't been sneakily swapped out by a DNS hack or something). The `known_hosts` weakness is that it can't detect a man-in-the-middle if it happens the *first time* you connect. By prepopulating the `/etc` file with known-good signatures the administrator can be sure that his users are not being snooped on.

Comment: I want to automate ssh set up for our development env. I put the same public key to authorized_keys and ~/.ssh/known_hosts. But I am getting warnning - man-in-the-middle attack. I am trying ssh localhost. Complain about different fingerprint

Comment: The `known_hosts` file does not have the same format as `authorized_keys`. I'm not really sure what the format *is*. I normally just let it auto-generate an entry and then copy it from my `known_hosts` to wherever I need it.

Comment: If I add public key to /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts - do I need restart ssh service? Because I face an interactive request for adding to known_hosts

Comment: I compared the keys from auhorized_key and known_hosts and the key differ in some section. Otherwise I have correct frmat. I am just trying to understand if I take this key from known_hosts and put it on different server will that work?

Comment: I believe `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file is only relevant on the client side, so there's nothing to restart.

Comment: I believe you can copy lines from one `known_hosts` file to another, and it'll work.

Comment: @ams Thanks, I now understand the difference between them. Now, if in the same machine exists both files `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` - what of them has more preference? I am assuming the former, right? - consider to update your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From the [ssh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) man page, [**FILES** section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html#FILES):

> `~/.ssh/known_hosts`
>
>   Contains a list of host keys for all hosts the user has logged
>   into that are not already in the systemwide list of known host
>   keys.  See sshd(8) for further details of the format of this
>   file.
>
> ...
>
> `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`
>
>   Systemwide list of known host keys. 
>   This file should be prepared
>   by the system administrator to contain the public host keys of
>   all machines in the organization.  It should be world-readable. 
>   See sshd(8) for further details of the format of this file.

[Here is the link to sshd(8).](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sshd.8.html#SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_FORMAT)

Comment: if in the same machine exists both files `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` - what of them has more preference? I am assuming the former, right? - consider to update your answer

Comment: It's a combined list. Normally no preference would be needed. I'm not sure what happens if a machine changes its fingerprint and only one file is updated. "See sshd(8) for further details."

Answer (score 1):

The  `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`   and   `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`
     files contain host public keys for all known hosts. The global file should be prepared by the administrator (optional),
     and  the per-user file is maintained automatically: whenever
     the user connects to an unknown host its key is  added  to
     the per-user file.

Comment: if in the same machine exists both files `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` - what of them has more preference? I am assuming the former, right? - consider to update your answer